# Error TikZ with mitwpl.cls

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to use TikZ with the MIT Working Papers in Linguistics `.cls` file (`mitwpl.cls`, available [here](http://mitwpl.mit.edu/publish/)). I use the following code:

```
\documentclass{mitwpl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
   test 
\end{document}
```

When I compile it, I get multiple errors like the following:

```
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen174
\pgfmath@count=\count154
\pgfmath@box=\box66
\pgfmath@toks=\toks32

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
               \protect 
l.134 ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}

? 
! Too many }'s.
<argument> ...x @\string \ensuremath {\rm \sb {a}}

l.134 ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}

? 
! Extra \endcsname.
\pgfmath@namedef ...ter \def \csname #1\endcsname 

l.134 ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}

? 

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.134 ...lmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ}

?
```

I don't understand the error messages. If I ignore them, an output is produced, like the following:

[image: output]

Any kind of tips or pointers are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class is not the best set up in the world. Here, the blocking issue is that it sets `_` and `^` to non-standard category codes, which causes all sorts of issues. We can at least get things to load with

```
\documentclass{mitwpl}
% Make 'safe'
\catcode`\^=7 %
\catcode`\_=8 %
\usepackage{tikz}
% Put back 'class expected' behaviour
\catcode`\^=\active
\catcode`\_=\active
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would be very wary of this class!

Comment: Yes, it's a really bad example of how not to implement a class. Especially because it provides modified versions of the example and glossing package `gb4e` which means that it will not reflect updates to that package. For example, the current version of `gb4e` contains a `\noautomath` command which undoes the catcode changes, but the version the class loads doesn't.